# How to draw meshes separately using the keyboard

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual C++2010 express with GLUT libraries, and I can easily draw different meshes all together in my - `void draw()` - function. After this I've tried to create different "phases" in animation function each one calling a different - `model.draw("object1")` -. Then when I try to use the keyboardown function changing the current phase it works at first, but as soon as I move the objects using the mouse the window turns black. Any hint?

That's the draw function that works:

```
void draw() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(  2, 2, -250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(spin_y, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(spin_x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);      

    model.Draw("object1");
    model.Draw("object2");

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

and that's the animation that doesn't works after deleting model.Draw("..."); from draw function:

```
void animation(int t)
{
    switch (phase) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            model.Draw("object2");
            glutSwapBuffers();
            break;
        case 2:
            model.Draw("object1");
            glutSwapBuffers();
            break;
    }
    glutTimerFunc((int) 1000/FPS, animation, 0);
}
```

and that's the keyboard func:

```
void keyboardDown(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

  switch(key) {
  case '1':phase=1;break;
  case '2':phase=2;break;
  case 'Q':
  case 'q':
  case  27:
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

This is the function that should make me move the objects using the mouse movement, updating the values of spin_x spin_y used in draw():

```
void mouseMotion(int x, int y) 
{
    spin_x = x - old_x;
    spin_y = y - old_y;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

and it works perfectly before deleting `model.draw(...)` in `draw()` functions, but when I try to use animation they just disappear. I've tried also adding `glutPostRedisplay()` after `model.draw(...)` in the `animation()` func but it still doesn't work.

And that is the main:

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int width = 800;
    int eight = 600;

glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(width, eight);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Perspective's GLUT Template");

glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardDown);
glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyboardUp);
glutMouseFunc(mouseClick);
glutMotionFunc(mouseMotion);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutDisplayFunc(draw);  
glutIdleFunc(idle);
glutTimerFunc((int) 1000/FPS, animation, 0);
glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(false); 


int subMenu = glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddMenuEntry("Do nothing", 0);
glutAddMenuEntry("Really Quit", 'q');


glutCreateMenu(menu);
glutAddSubMenu("Sub Menu", subMenu);
glutAddMenuEntry("Quit", 'q');
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

initGL(width, eight);

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

I've also added `glutSwapBuffers()` in animation func, don't know why I haven't wrote it first.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's pretty hard to guess what's going on/wrong.

Comment: Ok I'll do a better question including the code then

Comment: Updated, I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: The code you've posted still does not relate to your *"as soon as I move the objects using the mouse the window turns black"*. Where do you handle this and what do you do exactly?

Comment: Edited again, I hope with all the needed code to understand the problem now :)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the order of your transformations DO indeed make them animate in-place while visible and not just rotate out of view? Confirm this by dividing the rotate angles in "mouseMotion()" by a huge number so it takes a long time for them to disappear (if they do because of the transformations).

Comment: Dividing by a huge number it doesn't move at all, btw with glutSwapBuffers they don't disappear now, but it seems like the image is intermittent, it seems that the program just redraw everything instead of moving it...don't know what to do :S...

Comment: Solved...there were some misterious problems which just disappeared during the night...it works and the code is almost the same...  :-s